# How to use the default layout for nested controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty new to rails and I was building my routes to get a nested controller like this:

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    get 'operating_hour'
  end
  resources :services do
    member do
      get 'services'
    end
  end
end
```

Now, my layout for my applications is like this:

```
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>

  <% if main_side_view? %>
      <%= render 'layouts/main_side' %>
  <% elsif company_side_view %>
      <%= render 'layouts/company_side' %>
  <% else %>
      <h1><%= yield(:title) %></h1>
      <%= yield %>
  <% end %>

  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
```

All is working fine with my layout except all that is generated by the nested ('service') controller. When I go to a link of the nested controller my layout is not there!

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do it in a wrong way. You should create several layouts :

First, layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>

   <h1><%= yield(:title) %></h1>
   <%= yield %>

  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
```

Second, layouts/companies.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>
  Your code for companies
</div>
```

See the guide : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

You can create a shared view for flash messages.